# Extract difference between two strings (that are paths)

Tags: string, bash, shell, unix, path

## My wish:

Suppose we have two paths (they could contain spaces or any weird character). I'm interested to compare the filenames on the same folder, so for example

```
p1='/a/b/name xx_yy_home'
p2='/a/b/name xx_home'
```

These filenames, in general, could contain one of the following patterns among the other character leading and trailing them:

- `xx`
- `xx_yy`

One file contains `xx` and the other `xx_yy` at the same position of the former (so the two filenames differs only for `_yy`). Furthermore, I can guarantee that `$p1` is always longer than `$p2`.

I want to identify two such files (if they exists) stored `/a/b` folder. The part where I chose only two files in the same folder is trivial. My focus is on comparing the filenames.

## My attempts:

I tried the following (unsuccessfully):

`pd=$(comm -2 -3 <(echo "$p1") <(echo "$p2"))`

but it doesn't work since it prints a whole path. Also `diff` doesn't work. Even switching the order of `p1` and `p2` doesn't help.

How could I solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it have to be `_yy` specifically or is `yy_` acceptable? Offhand I bet most diff tools will return the latter, it will be hard to return the former without some additional clarification of how a script is supposed to know the difference.

Comment: It could be a start point getting yy_. For now, my problem is more bigger because it gives me as difference only one of the variables to be compared.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about your use case. What do you want to achieve by getting a variable set to `_yy` or `yy_`? What do you want to do with the value? Is there a guaranteee that the value of `p1` will always be the value of `p2` with some characters added in one place? Or could there be other differences. e.g. `/a/foo/name xx_home` vs. `/a/b/name xx_yy_home`? Or totally different strings with no common part?

Comment: What do you do when `p1=/a/b/name_xx_yy_home` and `p2=/a/b/C/name_zz_xx_home` ?

Comment: what do you expect if the filenames are `abc` and `def`? what do you expect if there are 5,000 files in the directory (ie, how do you determine which files to compare against each other)?

Comment: @markp-fuso I search only for those filenames containing the two patterns described above

Comment: I think this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). If you would tell us *in your question* what you want to do when you have identified a pair (or all pairs) of matching files, we might be able to suggest an alternative solution, e.g. looping over all files that match `*xx_yy_*` and check if a corresponding file exists where `xx_yy_` is replaced with `xx_`. I suggest to add an example directory listing that matches your real use case, e.g a few matching files, a few non-matching files, different directories if applicable, ...

Answer (score 1):

This will solve the immediate problem as stated, but with some caveats and assumptions.

First, the strings need to be the same other than the longer string having some added characters. Comparing strings that are really different creates a lot of problems with calculating what the differences are and how to present them. For example if you compare `foobar` and `hello world`...well, they both have two `o` and an `r`, how do you represent those differences here?

Second, this outputs `yy_` even though you asked for `_yy`. Both are valid differences if you just consider a difference to be "find the substring that I can delete to make these two strings the same," but any sane diff algorithm is going to give you `yy_` because `y` is where the two strings begin to differ on a character-to-character basis. If you want `_yy` you'll have to articulate a standard more specific than "find the difference."

```
#!/bin/bash
# ASSUMPTION: p1 is the longer string
p1='/a/b/name xx_yy_home'
p2='/a/b/name xx_home'

i=0 j=0
for (( ; i < "${#p1}" ; i++ )) ; do
  # compare each letter in both strings
  # if they don't match, print the mismatched character
  # and continue without advancing the pointer on the
  # shorter string
  if [[ "${p1:$i:1}" != "${p2:$j:1}" ]] ; then
    printf '%s' "${p1:$i:1}"
    continue
  fi
  ((j++))
done
echo # add a newline to the output
```

Comment: I rewrote the question to better focus my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could try starting with something fragile like this:

```
$ diff \
    <(printf '%s\n' "$p1" | sed 's/./&\n/g') \
    <(printf '%s\n' "$p2" | sed 's/./&\n/g') |
        awk -v ORS= 'sub(/< /,"")'
yy_
```

and massage further to do whatever you want for all of the other possible use cases not currently shown in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Possible alternative solution in `bash` based on incomplete requirements:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Loop over all files that contain xx_yy_
for p1 in /a/b/*xx_yy_*
do
    # Construct corresponding p2 by replacing xx_yy_ with xx_
    p2="${p1/xx_yy_/xx_}"

    # Check if the resulting file name exists
    if [ -f "$p2" ]
    then
        # do something with p1 and p2
        echo "$p1" vs "$p2"
    fi
done
```